# How to use id and facets with Solr

Tags: solr, facet

I have those kind of documents to index in Solr :

- title
- authorName
- authorId

I want to make a facet on the authorId field , but I want to display the authorName (the authorId is the better way to know if an author is different or not from an other author.

Do you think it's possible ?

Thanks a lot,

Antoine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you could facet on another field that is authorName and authorId concatenated (i.e. "John Grisham--332245", then before showing the facets you remove the authorId from the facet values.

Comment: I hoped that there was a native way to do that.

Thank you Mauricio for your answer.